# Getting max pagenumber when scraping website with python

Tags: python, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and have to scrape a website for some data for a course at university:

[Xrel](https://www.xrel.to/games-release-list.html?archive=2016-01)

I am able to get the information i need. The problem is i need it for every entry(page, month, year).

The amount of pages differs for every month. Is there any way to extract the maximum pagenumber so i can store it and use it for a loop?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For loops are nice but you can't always use them. In this case I would just repeatedly follow the link in the 'next page' button until there is no such button. Something like this:

```
url = <first page>
while True:
    # extract data
    if <there is a next page button>:
        url = <href of the button>
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get all your pages, yielding a BeautifulSoup object for each, the link to the next page is in the anchor tag with the class *forward*:

```
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin


def get_pages(base, url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    yield soup
    next_page = soup.select_one("a.forward")
    for page in iter(lambda: next_page, None):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(urljoin(base, page["href"])).content)
        yield soup
        next_page = soup.select_one("a.forward")



for soup in get_pages("https://www.xrel.to/", "https://www.xrel.to/games-release-list.html?archive=2016-01"):
    print(soup)
```

Comment: thx to you as well. But i have already implemented Alex' idea in my own solution. i did this with the forward class though

Comment: @Sannin, on another note, you should really be checking that you get the source back correctly and catching connection errors, just because you did not find the button would not necessarily mean that it was because you reached the last page